# PostgreSQL, How to keep only one schema?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, permissions

I don't want some users be available to create schemas, and only use the public schema.

I'd like to remove the permission of creating schemas, but I can't found anything on PotsgreSQL 9.1 documentation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `GRANT` says the following:

> CREATE
>
> ```
> For databases, allows new schemas to be created within the database.
>
> For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema. To rename an 
> existing object, you must own the object and have this privilege for the containing schema.
> ```

So let's simply try this.  I created a user for this purpose, and if you look at it, it has the `CREATEDB` attribute, just for clarifying which `CREATE` privilege refers to what.

```
CREATE USER schematest WITH LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD 'secure';

REVOKE CREATE ON DATABASE access_test FROM schematest;

GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO schematest;
```

These result in the following behaviour:

```
CREATE SCHEMA other_schema;

ERROR: permission denied for database access_test
SQL state: 42501
```

So far so good: the user cannot create a new schema.  Let's see if it can create objects in the `public` schema:

```
CREATE public.simple_table(id integer);

Query returned successfully with no result in 181 ms.
```

Hooray!

Comment: very good example!

Comment: How does `GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO schematest;` prove the ability of `schematest` to create objects in the schema `public`?

Comment: @Colin'tHart _"For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema."_  Or I don't understand the question.

Comment: You used `CREATE SCHEMA other_schema;` which returned an error to prove that `schematest` cannot create a new schema. I would've expected `CREATE TABLE public.test(col integer);` or something similar to prove that `schematest` can create objects in `public`.

Comment: Ah, I see - I managed to miss something from copy-paste, thanks for pointing that.